# getElementsByTagName and getElementsByClassName not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Sample Source:

```
 <div>      
            <br />
         <a name="IDATLQHE"></a>
        <h2 class="subhead" xmlns="">
         <div class="dummy">
             <div class="dummyy">
                <span>abcd</span>
            </div>

            <div class="dummyyy">
                <span>
                        <a title="google" href="http://google.com">google.com</a>
                </span>
          </div>                
        </div>
        </h2>       
    </div>
```

Output needed:

I want to replace the contents of the `<a>` element in the `<div class="dummyyy">`  element with the contents of the `<div class="dummyy">` element.

JavaScript written:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('dummy');
    for(var i = 0, len = divs.length; i < len; i++)
    {
        var div = divs[i],
        h2 = div.getElementsByClassName('dummyyy'),
        h3 = div.getElementsByClassName('dummyy');
        if(h2.length === 1)
        {
            var aa= h2[0],
            aaa=aa.getElementsByTagName('a');
            if(h2.length === 1 && h3.length === 1)
            {
                aaa[0].innerHTML = h3[0].innerHTML;
                h3[0].innerHTML=null;
            }
        }
    }
```

This script is working fine in Firefox, but not in IE.

Error at:

```
 getElementsByClassName 
 aaa=aa.getElementsByTagName('a')
```

Can any one help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` is not supported by IE8. If you don't require IE7 support, you can replace it with `div.querySelectorAll(".dummyy")`

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But I am still getting the error in aaa=aa.getElementsByTagName('a')

Comment: @User222 can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName()` is implemented by all current browsers except IE8 and earlier. IE8 does support `querySelectorAll()`