# What is the workaround for "getElementsByTagName" in IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ie8-browser-mode

What is the workaround for "getElementsByTagName" in IE8?

Comment: @GSerg — TagName, not ClassName.

Comment: @Quentin The workaround is the same. Both `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementsByClassName` are mentioned in other duplicate questions with same answers (e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11537336/11683))

Comment: @GSerg — The usual workaround for `getElementsByClassName` is "Use `getElementsByTagName` and filter it"! How can the "workaround" for `getElementsByTagName` be the same?!

Comment: @Quentin The workaround is "use `document.querySelectorAll("tag")`".

Comment: @GSerg — That's an alternative to `getElementsByTagName`, but not a workaround (since there isn't a problem with `getElementsByTagName` to work around.) It certainly isn't what the accepted answer on the question you marked as a duplicate says.

Comment: @Quentin As I said, you can use `querySelectorAll` to replace both `getElementsByTagName` (if you don't provide the dot in the selector) and `getElementsByClassName` (if you do). True it's not the accepted answer, which is sad but happens. On a secons thought, I should have voted for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11537336/11683) duplicate instead.

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer has supported `getElementsByTagName` since IE 5.5 (IE 6 for support for the `"*"` value as the argument).

There is no workaround, or need for one, for IE 8.