# querySelectorAll Vs getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, html

I learnt that collection returned by `getElementsByTagName` are live objects unlike the list returned by `querySelectorAll` or `querySelector`

In the sense, that, if there is an update in the webpage with new elements, collection returned by `getElementsByTagName` is also updated(if required)

So, from this aspect, Is the usage of `querySelector` not recommended?

Comment: It depends entirely upon what you're using it to do; sometimes you want a live NodeList, other times you don't. What use-case do you have in mind?

Comment: It also depends on wether or not you want to support IE8, which likely isn't much of an issue anymore

Comment: This cannot actually be answered besides telling you what you already mention in your question. You seem to understand what the difference is. When to apply what depends on said differences and the use case.

Comment: @adeneo: are you sure about the IE8 support issues, I recall it doesn't support `getElementsByClassName()`, but `getElementsByTagName()` seems to be supported, according to Quentin, since IE5.5 (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24033756/82548).

Comment: @DavidThomas - that's right, I was thinking of `..ByClassName`, *// needs to get glasses* ...